# Does exist a Python library to generate polygons avoiding antimeridian issues?

Tags: python, polygon, multipart, library, antimeridian

If I need to generate a polygon that crosses the anti-meridian, does it exists a Python library that treat such cases (partitioning such polygon and generate a multipart polygon)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a context of GeoJSON files (in which I was inserted) I've preferred to use a [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255619/60281) that uses `gdal.VectorTranslate` method, because it provides compliance to the RFC 7946 standard, that also [provides a rationale for antimeridian cases](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest looking into [Xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/quick-overview.html) here is a thread [xarray slicing across the antimeridian](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/205871/xarray-slicing-across-the-antimeridian) that covers a use for perhaps what you are looking for.

This thread isn't answered but provides another example [Shapely polygons crossing the antimeridian](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226605/shapely-polygons-crossing-the-antimeridian)

Here is a blog entry [How to correct a linestring for the antimeridian (180 longitude)](https://jamesgeo.com/2014/09/28/how-to-correct-a-linestring-for-the-antimeridian-180-longitude/) to provide additional context.

[image]

Comment: Nice suggestions. I've found another question on the same line using [`gdal.VectorTranslate`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/242561/60281). Have you tried to use this method? (I'm having issues to install `gdal` 2.1.x on my mac, so I haven't tested)

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try the line you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting a polygon along the antimeridian can potentially much more involved than expected. In Python, we can use the Shapely library to accomplish this with the following steps

1. Taking a given polygon's coordinates (in GeoJSON format), then detecting whether there are antimeridian crossings by checking if the **absolute value of the longitudinal difference** between two consecutive vertices of the polygon is greater than a certain threshold. Practically, 180 degrees could be a sensible threshold value.
2. If there are antimeridian crossing, you will next need to determine the direction (e.g. is it going from +179.9 to -179.9 or vice versa). Once you know the direction, you can shift certain vertices of the polygon into a new Cartesian space. For example, consider the case of the previous vertex at +179.9 the the current vertex at -179.9:

   - we can shift the current vertex to +180.1 in our new Cartesian space
   - we note down that the antimeridian crossing is a line at +180.0 of longitude
3. Once the entire polygon's vertices have been appropriately shifted into the new Cartesian space, we can then leverage Shapely's Cartesian geometry operations (particularly the `shapely.ops.split` function) to split the polygon safely.
4. Finally, for each of the resultant polygons from the `split` operation, you'll need to shift their longitude values to appropriate geographic coordinates (+/- 360.0)

Here's the [full tutorial + code snippets](https://towardsdatascience.com/around-the-world-in-80-lines-crossing-the-antimeridian-with-python-and-shapely-c87c9b6e1513) using Shapely.

Comment: Link-only answers risk deletion as non-answers.

Comment: Added high level overview of the logic