# gdal.VectorTranslate returns empty object

Tags: gdal, geojson, python-2.7

Having the following GeoJSON:

```
{"geometry": {"coordinates": [[[0.0, -89.9999999999], [0.0, -87.5], [120.0, -87.5], [120.0, -89.9999999999], [0.0, -89.9999999999]]], "type": "Polygon"}, "properties": {"grid_cell_index": 1}, "type": "Feature"}
```

I'm trying to load it with GDAL and to perform a VectorTranslate on it. The objective is to guarantee that is compliant to RFC 7946. My code is running on `Python 2.7.x` with `GDAL 2.2.1`:

```
from osgeo import gdal

srcDS = gdal.OpenEx('input.geojson')
ds = gdal.VectorTranslate('output.json', srcDS=srcDS, format = 'GeoJSON', layerCreationOptions = ['RFC7946=YES', 'WRITE_BBOX=YES'])
```

When I count the objects on the input:

```
srcDS.GetLayer(0).GetFeatureCount()
```

Returning **1**.

However, when I do the same count after transforming:

```
ds.GetLayer(0).GetFeatureCount()
```

It returns me **0**, and also the output.json file is *empty*. I've inverted my point coordinates but it seems that is not a right-hand error. Any ideas on what could be going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known python GDAL "[gotcha](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#Savingandclosingdatasetsdatasources)".  The data doesn't get written until the dataset is closed and dereferenced.

This works:

```
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()
srcDS = gdal.OpenEx('input.geojson')
ds = gdal.VectorTranslate('output.geojson', srcDS=srcDS, format = 'GeoJSON', layerCreationOptions = ['RFC7946=YES', 'WRITE_BBOX=YES'])

#Dereference and close dataset, then reopen.
del ds
ds = gdal.OpenEx('output.geojson')

print(srcDS.GetLayer(0).GetFeatureCount())
print(ds.GetLayer(0).GetFeatureCount())
```

Comment: Indeed it is a gotcha. Do you know the reason behind it? (Not that flushing an object is necessarily a problem)

Comment: I think it's a design choice of the underlying C++ library. The python bindings mostly just mirror the C++ rather than building a pythonic interface on top. A much more pythonic alternative is rasterio which is also built on top of gdal.