# Using ogr2ogr in Python scripts

Tags: arcpy, gdal, arcgis-pro, ogr, ogr2ogr

I have been trying to figure out how to execute ogr2ogr to convert files in Python script. I got it to work in Jupyter notebook within ArcGIS Pro and in the terminal but not in Python scripts. Here's the code I used in the notebook.

```py
import os,arcpy,shutil
from osgeo import ogr

abspath=os.path.abspath
abspath = os.path.abspath("__file__")
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)

ProjectFolder=dname

arcpy.env.workspace=ProjectFolder
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

! ogr2ogr siteboundary.shp Boundary.TAB

print("Conversion done,your file is located in "+ProjectFolder)
```

I searched a lot on how to use ogr commands in python script but had no luck. So I exported the notebook to a python script which was this.

```py
import os,arcpy,shutil
from osgeo import ogr
from IPython import get_ipython

abspath=os.path.abspath
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)

ProjectFolder=dname

arcpy.env.workspace=ProjectFolder
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

get_ipython().System("! ogr2ogr siteboundary.shp boundary.geojson")

print("Conversion done, your file is located in "+ProjectFolder)
```

But this script is giving me a 'NoneType' error

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "S:\TOOLS\Scripts.test\CT429_ContamCertificates_GIS\Untitled1.py", line 24, in 
> get_ipython().System("! ogr2ogr siteboundary.shp boundary.geojson")
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'System'"

So, I looked up nonetype error for system, found a really good resource "[Any idea why IPython.get_ipython() is returning None?](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12334)" but it's not working for me.

How can I do this?

I need this so that my team can run the Python scripts from the folder itself as that's more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use subprocess to execute ogr2ogr.exe in windows cmd/terminal.

From geojson to shape:

```
import subprocess

command = [r"C:\OSGeo4W\bin\ogr2ogr.exe", r"C:\GIS\data\lan.shp", r"C:\GIS\data\lan.geojson"]

output, error  = subprocess.Popen(
                    command, universal_newlines=True,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. I changed the command to this 
'command= [r"S:\TOOLS\Scripts\.test\ogr2ogr.exe", "siteboundary.shp", "geojson.json"]'
It works! Yes, I even changed the location of ogr2ogr.exe file to a relative location that is accessible by my team as well, and it works :)

Comment: I still find it strange how the ogr2ogr functionality isn't available via the python library. We must be missing something?

Comment: I dont know if it is/isnt. This is just the way I use ogr2ogr

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it (for fgb):

```
from osgeo import gdal
shpin = 'shpin.shp'
gdal.UseExceptions()
src_shp = gdal.OpenEx(shpin)

ds=gdal.VectorTranslate(
'abc.fgb',
src_shp,
options='-f "FlatGeobuf"'
)

del ds
```

All credit goes to these two threads:

[Using ogr2ogr to convert GML to shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39080/using-ogr2ogr-to-convert-gml-to-shapefile-in-python)

[gdal.VectorTranslate returns empty object](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255586/gdal-vectortranslate-returns-empty-object)